# What is the fallacy in the proof (given below) that $(n-2)! \equiv 1$ when $n$ is a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial

By Wilson's theorem we know that if $n$ is a prime number then $(n-1)! \equiv n-1 \pmod n$

So, upon division by $n-1$ on both the sides we have $(n-2)! \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Edit 1:
The teacher deducted marks in this proof and said that I've to consider the case for mod 2 separately. Also, her claim is verified by proof given  [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wilsons-theorem/?subtopic=modular-arithmetic&chapter=basic-applications) .

Comment: Why do you think there is a fallacy? Since $n-1$ is relative prime to $n$, you can divide like this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Proofs

that's not a fallacy; see the wikipedia article, in particular, "Proof Using the Sylow Theorems"

Comment: Perhaps it clarifies things for you if you write $(n-1)!\equiv -1\pmod n$ and remark that $n-1\equiv -1\pmod n$.

Comment: The teacher deducated marks in this proof and said that I've to consider the case for mod 2 separately.   Also, her claim is verified by proof given at https://brilliant.org/wiki/wilsons-theorem/?subtopic=modular-arithmetic&chapter=basic-applications"

Comment: Unless the teacher has issues with $0!$, there is no real reason to treat $2$ differently.

Comment: And even if that teacher has issues with $\;0!=1\;$ , deducing marks for that seems a little too harsh.

Comment: I don't think the proof you cite supports your teacher.  That is a proof of Wilson's theorem.  In your problem, you seem to be assuming Wilson's theorem, so the case $n=2$ is already included.

Comment: @B.Goddard No, in addition to the proof of Wilsons' theorem there is also a proof of this result in the page enclosed within a box.